# Docker daemon is not working

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I configured docker daemon socket.I am able to start docker engine by **"service docker start"**.If I try to check the status it display the content as 
**

```
> **"  docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor
> preset: disabled)    Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-25
> 17:55:35 IST; 49s ago
>      Docs: https://docs.docker.com  Main PID: 13942 (dockerd)    Memory: 22.7M    CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
>            ├─13942 /usr/bin/dockerd
>            ├─13948 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim
> docker-containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m
> --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --runtime docker-runc
>            └─14069 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 5000 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 5000 Aug 25 17:55:35 www.procifynow.com dockerd[13942]:
> time="2016-08-25T17:55:35.316805330+05:30" level=info msg="Daemon has
> completed initialization" Aug 25 17:55:35 www.procifynow.com
> dockerd[13942]: time="2016-08-25T17:55:35.316818523+05:30" level=info
> msg="Docker daemon" commit=23cf638 graphdriver=devicemapper
> version=1.12.1 Aug 25 17:55:35 www.procifynow.com dockerd[13942]:
> time="2016-08-25T17:55:35.321199525+05:30" level=info msg="API listen
> on /var/run/docker.sock" Aug 25 17:55:35 www.procifynow.com
> systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine. "**
```

**

but if i try to hit other commands like **docker ps or info**
It shows docker daemon is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run those commands with `sudo`.

Or if you don't want to do that add your user to the docker group like this:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
sudo service docker restart
```

That's what solved it for me at least.